# Let $f(x) = ax + b$ and $g(x) = cx + d$, where $a, b, c, d$ are constants. Determine for which constants $a, b, c, d$ it is true that $f ◦ g = g ◦$

Tags: functions

I'm working on this question and this what I did I get 
$f•g(x) = f(cx+d)=a(cx+d) + b = acx +ad + b
$
$g•f(x) = g(ax+b) = c(ax+b) + d = acx + cb + d
$
So how to I get  $f•g = g•f$?

Comment: Well, set the two things you got equal to each other first of all...

Comment: Then whats next?

Comment: Cancel the common term.

Comment: You cannot ask "then what's next"? within a minute of getting a suggestion. You need to **think** things through.

Answer (score 1):

We would like that
$$
acx+ad+b=acx+bc+d, 
$$ for all $x$, thus

> $$
> ad-bc=d-b.
> $$

Comment: I suppose it must be ad-d=bc-b factoring we get d(a-1)=b(c-1).