# Let $f(x)=ax+b$ and $g(x) = cx +d$. Determine necessary and sufficient conditions on the constants so that $f \circ g = g \circ f$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, logic

I want to ask a follow up question to this one: [Let $f(x) = ax + b$ and $g(x) = cx + d$, where $a, b, c, d$ are constants. Determine for which constants $a, b, c, d$ it is true that $f ◦ g = g ◦$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752139/let-fx-ax-b-and-gx-cx-d-where-a-b-c-d-are-constants-deter)

I thought the question was trying to establish an identity function:

I solve that $f \circ g= g \circ f$

$acx+ad+b=acx+bc+d$ factored to

$d(a-1)=b(c-1)$

So this mean that the following conditions are necessary and sufficient: $a \neq 1 \land b \neq 0 \land c \neq 1 \land d \neq 0$

But if I let $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{x}{a} - \frac {b}{a}$ and $g^{-1}(x) = \frac{x}{c} - \frac{d}{c}$ are the conditions $a \neq 0 \land c \neq 0 $ also necessary and sufficient?

Comment: The expression $f \circ g = g \circ f$ does not involve the function inverses, so there is no need to divide by $a$ or $c$.

Comment: I think your conclusion [before your last sentence] is also not right; just stay with the condition given in the answer to your other question.

Comment: @angryavian I was thinking if I wanted to solve for any of constants for example $d$ then $(a-1)$ could not be $0$ and vice versa.

Comment: The question is not asking you to solve for the constants; there will be many different possible solutions. They are just asking you to find a condition on the constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(f\circ g)(x) = a(cx + d) + b = ac x +ad + b\\
(g\circ f)(x) = c(ax + b) + d = ac x +bc + d$

$(f\circ g)(x) = (g\circ f)(x) \implies bc + d = ad +b$
or $d(a-1) = b(c-1)$

$f$ or $g$ is the identity function.  i.e. $a= 1$ and $b = 0$ and $f(x) = x$

or

$\frac {d}{c-1} = \frac {b}{a-1}$